# Javascript AJAX call fails in firefox when return false;

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox

There are several questions similar to this but they don't appear to be the same so here it goes?

I have a website in which I have a login form. I want to use ajax to call a php function and while everything works fine in chrome.  In firefox when I click the login button which which triggers the logIn() javascript function I get redirected to the javascript:logIn() page which is white and just says false.  If I remove the return false in the logIn() method it appears to work fine.

```
<form  method="post" id="loginform" action="javascript:logIn()">
    <div>
        <input type="text" value="Username..." name="username" id="username" onfocus="defaultInputUsername(this)" onblur="clearInputUsername(this)" />
        <input type="text" value="Password..." name="passwordText" id="passwordText" onfocus="setPass()"/>
        <input type="password" value="" name="password" id="password" onfocus="defaultInputPassword(this)" onblur="checkPass()" />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Login" name="Submit"/>
        <a href="create-account.php" id="create"><span>Create Account</span></a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Above is the form which calls the logIn() javascript method which is found below:

```
function logIn() {
    var action = "check-login.php";
    var form_data = {
        username : $("#username").val(),
        password : $("#password").val(),
        is_ajax : 1
    };

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : action,
        data : form_data,
        success : function(response) {
            if(response != 'failed')
                $("#loginform").slideUp('slow', function() {
                    $("#login_response").html('<ul id="usernav" class="sf-menu sf-js-enabled sf-shadow"><li><div id="message"></div><ul><li><a href="#"><span>View Profile</span></a></li>  <li><a href="#" onclick="logOut()"><span>Logout</span></a>  </li></ul></li></ul>');
                    $("#message").html('<a id="userlink" href="#"><span>' + response + '</span></a>');
                    $("ul.sf-menu").superfish({
                        animation : {
                            height : 'show'
                        }, // slide-down effect without fade-in
                        delay : 800, // 1.2 second delay on mouseout
                        autoArrows : false
                    });
                });
            else {
                $("#username").css("border", "2px red inset");
                $("#password").css("border", "2px red inset");
            }
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

If someone could tell me when it works in chrome and not firefox and if I should be using return false at all.  That would be awesome.

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

This is very unconventional code so it's a bit difficult to answer fully.

To hack the thing together I would change your action= to an onsubmit=. "action" was not intended for this.

```
<form ...stuff... onsubmit="return logIn();">
```

The return false in an onsubmit will prevent the page from posting. Make sure you note that it's **returning** the result of logIn(), which in your case is always false.

You could also do:

```
onsubmit="logIn(); return false;"
```

and remove the return false from your logIn function.

**Note**: The ajax call is async by default.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I did try using onsubmit but something else about it broke, I will have to try it again.  Could you explain a bit more about why the code is unconventional.  Also is it better to use return false or e.preventDefault();

Comment: @Nath5 - personally, I think it is better to get all the event handlers OUT of the markup and IN the code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using jQuery, why not set the action-attribute to a page that logs in the user if user has JavaScript disabled, and then add some javascript that automatically binds the submit-button to use your logIn()-function

Something like this would probably work (haven't tested it, but it should work):

```
//When document is ready/loaded
$(document).ready(function () {

    //Register click handler for submit-button with id "submit"
    $("#submit").click(function(event) {
        //call javascript and prevent postback
        event.preventDefault();
        logIn();
    });
}
```

and your loginform could look something like this:

```
<form  method="post" id="loginform" action="login-page-without-javascript.php">
```